# Discrete Logarithm problem with inverse

Tags: reference-request, discrete-logarithm, hardness-assumptions

Let $\mathbb G$ be a cyclic group of order $q$. The Discrete Logarithm Problem (DLP) is, given $g, g^x \in \mathbb G$, to compute $x \in \mathbb Z_q $.

I'm interested to know if there is a known variant of DLP as follows:

> Given $g, g^x, g^{x^{-1}\bmod q} \in \mathbb G$, compute $x \in \mathbb Z_q$

It is clear that this variant would not be harder than the DLP, since a DLP solver could be used to solve this problem simply by ignoring the third input.

Comment: try to find a copy of this report: ICT-2007-216676
ECRYPT II
European Network of Excellence in Cryptology II. They collect many computational hypothesis and gave all the definitions. (a link to the final version: http://cordis.europa.eu/docs/projects/cnect/6/216676/080/deliverables/001-DMAYA6.pdf)

Comment: @ddddavidee I'm familiar with that report and I'm afraid the answer is not there :(

Comment: In what group is $1/x$ computed, or/and how is $g^{1/x}$ defined? How does that differ from $g^{-x}$, which has an accepted definition (and would make it trivial that the problem is equivalent to the DLP) ?

Comment: @fgrieu Maybe I'm abusing the notation: $1/x$ is actually $x^{-1} \mod q$

Comment: @cygnusv: now that's all clear to me; $1/x$ is modulo $q$, the order of $g$; that's a most natural notation (and ah you made it even clearer; would be a good use case for `\bmod` rather than `\mod`, though; and $x \in \mathbb Z_q$ is enough in any case). The difficulty might also depend on if $q$ is a given or not. In either case I know no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem seem to be equivalent to a particular instance of the $k$-**Strong Discrete Logarithm Problem**.

Let $\mathbb G$ be a cyclic group of order $q$. The $k$-**Strong Discrete Logarithm Problem** ($k$-DLP) is, given $h, h^x, h^{x^2}, .., h^{x^k} \in \mathbb G$, to compute $x \in \mathbb Z_q $. Taking a simple change of variable ($h^x = g$), one obtains an equivalent version of the problem, which is as follows:

> Given $g^{x^{-1}\bmod q}, g, g^x, ..., g^{x^{k-1}} \in \mathbb G$, compute $x \in \mathbb Z_q $

It can be seen then that the problem in the question is the case of $k=2$.

The $k$-Strong Discrete Logarithm Problem is discussed in [Correlated-Input Secure Hash Functions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/233.pdf) by Goyal, O'Neill, and Rao, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the *Strong-DDH: strong decision Diffie-Hellman problem*. See [Final Report on Main Computational Assumptions in Cryptography](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/ecrypt2/documents/D.MAYA.6.pdf). Assumption number 19.

If the DDH is hard then this implies that it must also be hard to calculate the discrete log.

Comment: I think this is wrong. The problem I am asking is, ultimately, to compute a discrete logarithm (in other words, a computational problem), while the strong-DDH is a decisional problem. In fact, a solver for the problem I am asking can be used for solving the strong-DDH problem, while the opposite does not seem to be true. 
PD: Sorry for not commenting before, I got interrupted at work.

Comment: However, it does seem analogous to the Strong-DDH problem but transposed to the Discrete Logarithm. Maybe something like the "Strong Discrete Logarithm problem"...

Comment: [Bingo](http://research-srv.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/vipul/cihash-full.pdf). I withdraw the (-1) as a thank you for the inspiration :)

Comment: Apply logical contraposition to the implication in your comment and you get the  resukt that your problem is not solveable.